# Google+ theme catch partial update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I been trying to create a theme for google plus that would make it black, blue, and white using javascript/jquery in an chrome extension.  The problem I am running into is when ever you click on a link like the photos button it does not rerun the script on page load. Though when you refresh the photos page it runs and looks right. The same thing happens on the home page when you scroll down. The new content that it loads does not hold to my settings.

I am new to javascript/jquery so this has been bugging me for days now.

here is the code i have.

```
function init() {
var newHTML='<a href="http://plus.google.com/"><img id="gbqld" class="gbqldr" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/google-logo-plus-0fbe8f0119f4a902429a5991af5db563.png" alt="Google Products"></a>';  
document.getElementById('gbqlw').innerHTML = newHTML;  
}  
window.onload = init;  
$(document).ready(function() {  

$(".gC").css("background-color", "#111111");  
$(".gC").css("color", "white");  
$(".k-B-yd-nb-NH-wf").css("background-color", "#111111");  
$("div").css("background", "#111111");  
$("div").css("color", "white");  
$(".k-B-fa-wf-mf").css("background-color", "#111111");  
$(".Ku").css("color","#3366cc");  
$(".roster_name").css("color","#3366cc");  
$(".YmkEXd").css("background-color", "#111111");  
$(".TvDVZb").css("background-color", "#111111");  
$(".Lhhrrd").css("background-color", "#111111");  
$(".Lhhrrd").css("background-color", "#111111");  
$(".gbts").css("color","#3366cc");  
$(".gbto").css("color","#3366cc");  
$(".e-Ia-If").css("color","black");  
});
```

So my question is how to I catch the partial load so that I am able to run my script again to make sure it applies it self to the new content.

Thanks in advance for the help and suggestions.
-Local Tech Repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your script inject a CSS stylesheet into the document, rather than statically restyling all these elements. What you're doing now is the equivalent of going through the document, picking out each element with the classes you're specifying, and giving each one a `style="..."` attribute.

You can inject a stylesheet by creating a `<style>` element and inserting it into the document.

Comment: i have tried injecting a style sheet via content_scripts in the chrome extension though. many of my styles get over written by google+ styles. even when I run at document end. that is why I had turned to editing each class.

Comment: Use `!important` if your style are getting overridden.